# wordpress website AWS taking too long to load

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, bitnami

I have a website running on wordpress (Bitnami).the server is on an AWS behind an elastic load balancer. However, when i hit the wordpress website, it is taking too long to respond.

There is another nodejs API that is running on the same  AWS server (on port 4000). That is returning a response pretty fast. So, this would not be a DNS resoulution issue.

Any idea how i can debug the reason why the wordpress website is taking too long to load?

Comment: What do you consider too long? Wordpress out of the box always performs poorly. You need a lot of caching a wordpress site.

Comment: What does "too long to load" mean? Does it mean that you're not seeing _anything_, as @chriswilliams thinks? Or is it taking longer than you think it should (and if yes, why)? Or is it taking longer than some other deployment (and if so, how much)? Or something else?

Comment: @jordanm: It is taking almost 10-12 seconds to load. Even by wordpress standards 2-3 seconds should be the maximum time. Since there is no database calls. Its just a static page (using a wordpress template)
It is taking much longer than other deployments: 1) A nodejs API running on the same server (on port 4000). 2) A static html file being served without any wordpress template.

Answer (score 1):

This will likely be a security group issue judging on the behaviour you're experiencing.

Ensure the following:

- The Load Balancers security group allows inbound access (port `80` for `HTTP`, port `443` for `HTTPS`)
- The instances security group allows inbound access from the load balancer (on the port the application should be loaded from).
- Check the [health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html) of the host in the load balancer interface within the console.
- If the database is external to the instance host (i.e. another server or RDS) then ensure it supports inbound access from the instance (port `3306` for MySQL).
- If the database is running on the same server (the default for bitnami) ensure it is connecting to the host as `localhost`.